# Display count of open issues on JIRA gadget

Tags: jira

I need help in querying the hsqldb of my JIRA instance to find count of open issues in each project and display this data on my gadget. What do I need to use ? Can it be done directly using jql ? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it to be as simple as parsing the searchrequest.xml file and getting count of the <items> elements. But still need to know how to display some calculated values derived from database fields, onto the Jira dashboard plugin.

Comment: Hi Emerlad, is it possible to see what you did? I am having to do something similar at work. I'm trying to get open issues and change status counts per project.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version JIRA Cloud now has a *Filter Count* gadget available, which seems to do what you need:
[image: Adding JIRA Filter counts gadget]

Here's how it looks like in the wild:

[image: JIRA Filter counts gadget in action]

It should eventually make it into JIRA Server, as most features do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could do that out-of-the-box, but you could do this by using using [JQL Tricks Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/31399).
If you wish to design something of your own you could query [Jira using the remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) and save the results as an HTML page. Than  you could use [Jira Custom Content Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.tngtech.jira.plugins.customcontent.jira-gadget-custom-content)
 the to show the page in the dashboard. Finally schedule the query to run every minute or so.

Hope that this answers your questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create filter that lists issues you want to count (e.g. bugs that are open, re-opened, etc)
   Filters are created in Issues/Search for issues
2. Create dashboard 
    Dashboards/Manage Dashboards ...
3. Add Issue statistics gadget to the dashboard
4. Configure Issue statistics gadget to use filter you created in the step 1.
5. Configure other parameters of the gadget

   - sorting order
   - statistics type (I used component, affect how statistics will be grouped)

By this way I have created dashboard that shows number of open bugs per each component in the project.

We are using Jira version 6.0.5